# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath / popViewControllerAnimated do not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I use

> tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath / popViewControllerAnimated

it does not work. I push the view controller by another view but when I select a row, it highlights in gray instead of immediately popping to the original view controller. But when I tap another row, it selects the first row I tapped and then goes back to the original view controller.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    NSArray *allTypes = [[ItemStore sharedStore] allTypes];
    NSManagedObject *raum = allTypes[indexPath.row];
    self.an.leben = raum;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacde `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

The delegate method you have written is `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
According to apple, tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
Tells the delegate that the specified row is now **deselected**.

and

tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
Tells the delegate that the specified row is now **selected**.

So, what is happening is, when you click on a row, it becomes selected and turns gray and then when you click on the same or any other row, the previous one gets deselected because only one row is selected at once  and hence calls this method to open the next view controller with the previous tapped row.

Answer (score 0):

Change `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` into `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.